Подключение OpenLiteSpeed сервера к уже готовому сайту на WordPress
Такой вопрос: имеется веб-сайт на VPS сервере (система Debian 10.0) на движке WordPress. Обращался в тех. поддержку хостинга по поводу установки на него OpenLiteSpeed сервера. Саппорт ответил, что это можно сделать, однако сразу после установки, сайт перестанет работать, до тех пор, пока через SSH не будет выполнена конфингурация OpenLiteSpeed с WordPress.
Собственно, вопрос: а каким именно образом можно прикрутить OpenLiteSpeed к уже существующему сайту на WP? Сколько статей в инете не находил, везде пишется только о том как установить и настроить OpenLiteSpeed сервер, и затем установить туда свежий WP, но нигде не нашел информации по поводу того как настроить OpenLiteSpeed на уже готовом веб-сайте.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Вопорос и серии "Как построить дорогу под движущимся автомобилем". Учи матчать.

Та наверное ни как... Вопрос из разрята, как на компютер поставить новую ОС не используя текущую, и без доступа к BIOS. У вас на севере уже что-то стоит по типу Apache или nginx вы это удаляете, ставите новый сервер... (*поверив рекламе), разворачиваете WP.
Можно на отдельном сервере, развернуть ваш OpenLiteSpeed, а потом перенаправить DNS и прочюю шляпу, что б оно точно работало ... если вам прям кретично, что б ваши пользователи не увидили неработающий сайт. Когда IP сменяться пользователей будет бросать на ваш новый сервер.

Спасибо, дело в том, что саппорт ответили следующее, цитирую:
«Благодарю Вас за вопрос. Если Вы желаете я могу остановить web сервера Apache и Nginx и в ручную установить для Вас OpenLiteSpeed. Так как FASTPANEL не поддерживает OpenLiteSpeed, то добавлять в нее конфигурацию сайты и настраивать их работу с данным Web сервером Вам нужно будет самостоятельно через SSH.»
Как-то так. Извиняюсь, если глупый вопрос, просто не знал куда еще можно обратиться за помощью.

Вопрос не глупый, просто вы пытаетесь поставить что-то специфическое на сервер. Вас просто предупредили что отвественность за эту вещьпотом будет на вас... Ddos атаки, сброс кешей и прочее в будещем саппорт от вас будет морозиться, если у вас с ним возникнут проблемы. Вам поставят, дальше сами.

Теперь понял, спасибо вам большое за ответ. Как раз-таки за эти "подводные камни" хостинг мне и не сказал.

"....с данным Web сервером Вам нужно будет САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО через SSH" . Та вроде сказал SMTP почта... Cron.... это всё сами.
